# AWS Cloudwatch Logs timestamp parsing with milliseconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a hive-server2 log that's formatting its output with timestamps like:

```
2017-09-19T18:04:39,717 ERROR [words.
```

But the `datetime_format` [spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) doesn't list any support for milliseconds. There is only zero padded microseconds `%f` -> `000000 ... 999999`.

So I tried to specify most of the string as follows:

```
datetime_format = %Y-%m-$dT%H:%M:%S,
```

But I'm getting parse warnings for this in the `/var/log/awslogs.log`. It would appear that it's trying to use the format to match the whole first white-space separated field, or maybe using it to find where to start splitting on whitespace and then expecting the `717` part to be a log level.

Does anyone know which it is and also whether there's some way for me to write a regex equivalent of `.*`, `\d*` or `\S*` for after the comma?

Comment: I've also opened this with AWS support with similar silence.

Comment: I might have a similar problem.
Using `datetime_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`
and parsing the message
`{"@timestamp":"2018-03-13T10:15:06.522+00:00", "message":"Hello World"}`
I'll get an error `timestamp could not be parsed from message`.
awslogs is version 1.1.4

Comment: I would love an answer to this that I could accept.

Comment: Thanks 2018q3 to 2019q2

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=166865